# dynamic query in where clause for linq using c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have this below code where i filter out type which are not of "type1".

```
List = Details.Where(p => p.Type != Constants.Type1).ToList();
```

Now i have to create the where query dynamically in which i can have more clauses for filtering data.

so a modified version of above code is

```
List = Details.Where(p => p.Type != Constants.Type1 && p.Type != Constants.Type2 ).ToList();
```

Please advice how i can achieve this in c#

Comment: not sure how asp.net is related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ExcludedTypes = new Type[] { Constants.Type1, Constants.Type2 };
List = Details.Where(p => !ExcludedTypes.Contains(p.Type)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just call `Where` multiple times (remembering that that won't affect the query you call it on; just the return value). For example:

```
var query = Details.Where(p => p.Type != Constants.Type1);
if (avoidType2)
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.Type != Constants.Type2);
}
List = query.ToList();
```

EDIT: Note that I'd use this approach for *general purpose* dynamic filtering. If you always want to filter just by type, and it's just the list of valid types that varies, then I'd use George's approach.

Comment: but in your code won't it iterate twice 1 for checking for type1 and then again for type2. Can't i do this in one shot?

Comment: @Amit: No, it won't. The *exact* behaviour will depend on your provider (e.g. LINQ to SQL vs LINQ to Objects) but the *logical* result is that each filter is applied *in turn* to each item returned from the query. Note that the `Where` call does *not* perform the iteration itself, due to the lazy nature of LINQ.

Comment: So do you mean that when you do "List = query.ToList();" in your code that's where the actual filtering is done instead of places where we have called the "where" method?

Comment: @Amit: Yes, exactly that. I *strongly* recommend that you read up on how LINQ works before using it too much more. It's really important to get into the right mindset.